# c++ how to store data as a 32 bit unsigned int

Tags: c++

I am looking to store a piece of data as a 32 bit unsigned int in c++.  Any ideas of how to do this? I was thinking about using a char somehow but im not sure how it would work

Comment: char has size of 8bits, and can therefore not store a 32bit value unless you have an array of 4 char's - but that would be called an int.

Comment: What the hell is wrong with regular *32 bit unsigned int in c++*?

Comment: @GreenScape ints can be 16 bit. I'm assuming that's why he asked the question.

Comment: A `char` does not have to be 8 bits.  It does have to be 1 byte, though.

Comment: While the question is somewhat fuzzy, it can be answered and was answered. This actually turned out to be a rabbit hole for me. I assumed int on modern machines would be 64bit and that is not usually the case, though it should be. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17489857/5276890. Finally, quoting Henry Spencer, "Beware, in particular, of the subtle and terrible 'All the world's a
X32-bit machine', which is almost true today but shall cease to be so
before thy resume grows too much longer." He turned out to be wrong.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <cstdint>
```

and then use `uint32_t`

Answer (score 2):

To use cross platform standards, you can use

```
uint32_t variable;
```

Be sure to include "stdint.h" if you are working on a windows platform.

For more information, visit the Wikipedia page for standard integers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h

Comment: cstdint is the c++ equivalent.