# Why is int being treated as a 32 bit value when compiled x86_64

Tags: c++, x86-64

For this code:

```
int
alpha(int n)
{
    n += 3;
    return n;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 1231231;

    int m = alpha(n);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled x86_64, the int is treated as 32 bits:

https://godbolt.org/z/UceAtE

Note in particular this assembly in the compiled alpha function:

```
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $3, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
```

See that it is pulling 4 bytes (32 bits) for the int parameter.

On an 64 bit architecture, however, I would have expected an int to be treated as 64 bits. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [SO: Why is int typically 32 bit on 64 bit compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17489857/7478597).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: x64 means memory addresses are 64bit (increasing maximum limit of memory size of the system), it has nothing to do with `int` size.

Comment: @Scheff and Kamil: yes that answers my question. I did not see that in a search nor was it suggested as I wrote this question. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, if you want a integer of a specific size, use the `(u)intN_t` types.

Comment: I found even more suprising that `long` has different sizes in x64 when I compared VS2013 (32 bit) with `g++` (in cygwin64 64 bit). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff *Nix uses LP64, while Windows uses LLP64.  ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: `int` is 32 bit on *some* 64 bit platforms. On others it is 64 bit. All the standard guarantees you is that `int` is equal in size *or* larger than `short` and at least 16 bits, so both are fine.